# Wrapping image in a DIV while preserving existing grid flexibility

Tags: css

I currently have a grid of images that scales appropriately depending on the size of the window and container.

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/2zND2/13/

So far I have tried and failed to wrap a DIV around the images without breaking the existing structure. How can I do this?

CSS

```
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  #photos img {
  /* 5 images wide */
  width: 19.2% ; margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
  }
  #photos img:nth-child(5n) { margin: 0 0 1% 0; }
}

@media (min-width:800px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos img {
  /* 5 images wide */
  width: 19.2% ; margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
  }
  #photos img:nth-child(5n) { margin: 0 0 1% 0; }
}

@media (min-width:400px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos img {
  /* 4 images wide */
  width: 24.25% ; margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
  }
  #photos img:nth-child(4n) { margin: 0 0 1% 0; }
}

@media (min-width:300px) and (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos img {
  /* 2 images wide */
  width: 49% ; margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
  }
  #photos img:nth-child(2n) { margin: 0 0 2% 0; }
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
  #photos img {
  /* 1 image wide */
  width: 100% ; margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean a `div` around each image, or around the whole block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's the final result that you should get after applying the steps I'm about to mention: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/EV7Kc/).

**1)** Wrap each `img` in a `div`.

**2)** Add a CSS rule:

```
#photos div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**3)** Change all your selectors `#photos img` to `#photos div`.

**4)** Add:

```
#photos div img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I really appreciate that. I think it was the display property that I had wrong.